# I have a Ubuntu (18.04) with two monitors, one 3840x2160 (4K) and one 1920x1080, but there are problems with the two displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have an Ubuntu (18.04) with two monitors, one 3840×2160 (4K) and one 1920×1080, but there are problems with the two displays. I want the 4K display to be scale of 200% and scale of 100% 1920×1080 display.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Open **Settings** then choose **Devices**. You'll find your monitors listed. choose the one you want to change its scale and then you'll find **scale** with two options: one is 100% and the other is 200%, choose the option you want.

Comment: I want two monitors to display different scale.

Comment: I have the same issue: changing the scaling for one display also changes the scaling for the other display, which is unfortunate.

Comment: I have an NVidia GPU, one screen plugged to it in DisplayPort (4K) and the secondary screen (1920x1080) plugged in to the HDMI port of the GPU. I have tried to play with the xrandr command but with no luck so far, and the Nvidia X Server app is not so simple to use either...